# How to delete duplicate records in my database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssms, duplication

I joined about 12 databases into 1 db and in each database I have some duplicate records.

How can I delete all duplicate records in my joined database?

For example, I want to delete duplicate records when data in column "phone" is the same.

Comment: Do you really want to *delete* the data or just not show them in the query results?

Comment: @jkavalik yeah, I'm sure, I want to delete duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have no foreign key constraints on the `phone` column and you have a Primary Key defined:

```
DELETE FROM foo_schema.bar_table
WHERE primary_key_column NOT IN (SELECT MAX(primary_key_column)
                                        FROM foo_schema.bar_table
                                        GROUP BY phone)
```

This should group all records by the column `phone`, and drop all the duplicates but the one with the *max* PK. Hope that helps.

Please try this on a dummy table before attempting this on your actual table.

Comment: this is what I want, exactly! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390574/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server